# Append a string to a variable and store it in same variable in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

suppose we have a variable in XSLT:

`<xsl:variable name="abc" select="Try">`

i want to append a string "XSLT" to the variable 'abc', so that when i access this variable 'abc' i get the value as "Try XSLT".

```
<variable>
<xsl:value-of select="$abc">
</variable>
```

i get:

`<variable>Try XSLT</variable>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat($abc, ' XSLT')"/>
```

Comment: Hi Michael thanks for the answer
but i want the whole concatenated value in the variable 'abc' so when i call

<xsl:value-of select="$abc"/> i get the value as 'Try XSLT'

is this possible in XSLT?

Comment: You can trivially declare a new variable whose value is `concat($abc, ' XSLT')`, but you can't modify the contents of an existing variable - remember that you are dealing with a functional language here.